# How to have many configurations of a task in gradle builds?

Tags: java, gradle, build, jmh

I am currently using a plugin to run benchmarks on Java code, and I used [jmh-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin) to do that.

The plugin allows to conveniently describe JMH configurations with a `jmh` code block:

```
jmh {
    include = ["List"]
    benchmarkParameters=["seed": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
        "applicationSize":["100", "1000"],
        "baseStructureSize":["100", "1000"]]
    fork=2
    timeOnIteration="250ms"
    iterations=2
    warmup="250ms"
    warmupIterations=2
    fork=2
    resultFormat="CSV"
    benchmarkMode=["ss"]
    timeUnit="ms"
    failOnError = true
}
```

This is useful, but I would like to have different types of the same task, for instance, one where the output is CSV, one where the output is JSON. I know this can be configured with `resultFormat=<format>`, but I could not find a way to "duplicate" a task and have a different configuration for each variant.

The [Gradle documentation has a page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configuring_tasks) about configuring tasks, but they configure a `Copy` task. I thought I could follow a similar approach and write:

```
task myJMH(type: me.champeau.gradle.JMHTask) {
    resultFormat="JSON"
}
```

But approach does not work, as I mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin/issues/161). I think it might be that the JMH task is just different. Registering a class of that name works, but it's not possible to configure it. I get the following error:

```
Could not set unknown property 'include' for task ':myJMH' of type me.champeau.gradle.JMHTask.
```

Similarly, I would like to have various configurations of the `shadowJar` task, to be able to generate several different variants of the task, but I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `jmh` in your first example is not a task, but an *extension*. The plugin registers both an extension and a task with the same name. Actually, this is a prevalent pattern for Gradle plugins.

Usually, even if the tasks created by a plugin may be configured using an extension, it is still possible to configure them directly, as they still provide configuration properties. This is the case for the task type `ShadowJar`, so you can [simply create tasks of that type manually](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/custom-tasks/):

```
// Shadowing Test Sources and Dependencies
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

task testJar(type: ShadowJar) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output
    configurations = [project.configurations.testRuntime]
}
```

Sadly, the task type `JMHTask` is implemented in a way that it simply retrieves the configuration from the extension, so any instance will use the same configuration.

However, you may try the following workaround:

Create tasks that configure the extension and then wire them to be executed together with the `jmh` task:

```
jmh {
    include = ["List"]
    benchmarkParameters=["seed": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
        "applicationSize":["100", "1000"],
        "baseStructureSize":["100", "1000"]]
    fork=2
    timeOnIteration="250ms"
    iterations=2
    warmup="250ms"
    warmupIterations=2
    fork=2
    benchmarkMode=["ss"]
    timeUnit="ms"
    failOnError = true
}

task jmhCsv {
    doFirst {
        jmh.resultFormat="CSV"
    }
    finalizedBy 'jmh'
}

task jmhJson {
    doFirst {
        jmh.resultFormat="JSON"
    }
    finalizedBy 'jmh'
}
```

Please note that a task may only be executed once in a build, so this workaround won't work if you want to run different configurations in the same run.